# I have used facebook login in app works on Andorid Emulator but not on actual Android device

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

What should I do, *Facebook login* works on Emulator but not on actual device

Comment: after uninstalling facebook app it works

Comment: you would have added generated hashKey in facebook console for the emulator, you have to do same for each and every device you are testing

Comment: @ArunShankar I generated hash key and it only works on Emulator or device which not have installed facebook app, how can I generate separate hash keys and how to generate final hash key for publish

Comment: refer this fb doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

The final step of facebook login authentication states that,

> Create a Development Key Hash
>
> Facebook uses the key hash to authenticate interactions between your
>   app and the Facebook app. If you run apps that use Facebook Login, you
>   need to add your Android development key hash to your Facebook
>   developer profile.
>
> For the version of your app that you release to you also need to
>   generate and set a Release Key Hash.
>
> On either OS X or Windows you can get a key has by generating it or by
>   using the value returned by Settings.getApplicationSignature(Context).
>   For instructions, see Running Sample Apps .

It is because you haven't done this, you're getting this error!
Check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Please check mode as release or debug in facebook app development. apart from that need to generate and set a Release Key Hash.

Answer (score 0):

very old question but I found how to resolve. Just use

```
LoginManager.getInstance().loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY
```

or

```
LoginManager.getInstance().loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY
```

and installed app will not bother you